# JavaScript Accordion in a different element

Tags: javascript, accordion

I'm trying to do a accordion when the click on "show" to show the full profile from a list of profiles and close it with another button.

So far what I've done

```
<div class="short-pro">
<button class="show">Full Profile</button>
</div>
<div class="full-pro">
<button>close</button>
</div>

<div class="short-pro">
<button class="show">Full Profile</button>
</div>
<div class="full-pro">
<button>close</button>
</div>

<div class="short-pro">
<button class="show">Full Profile</button>
</div>
<div class="full-pro">
<button>close</button>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var show = document.getElementsByClassName('show');
var full= document.getElementsByClassName('full-pro');

for (i = 0; i < accbtn.length; i++) {
 show[i].addEventListener("click", activeBtn());
}

function activeBtn() {
for (i = 0; i < active.length; i++) {
 full[i].classList.add("active");
 }
}
```

Note: close button not tried yet.

I hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. You should mark variable i as let
2. You should pass i to activeBtn function

So, you code should be like this:

```
var show = document.getElementsByClassName('show');
var full = document.getElementsByClassName('full-pro');
var close = document.getElementsByClassName('close');


for (let i = 0; i < show.length; i++) {
  show[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    activeBtn(i); 
 });
}

for (let i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    deactiveBtn(i); 
  });
}

function activeBtn(i) {
  full[i].classList.add("active");
}

function deactiveBtn(i) {
  full[i].classList.remove("active");
}
```

You can see full example in sandbox: https://jsfiddle.net/73ktn6hc/3/#&togetherjs=t0jU1L4mI2